# Read XML commented value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Helo,
I have an XML file. I want to do read commented value(100001) and line number.
PHP/Ajax auto complete need, when I put serial number in textbox, it should show XML line number and commented value inside another 2 textboxes.
I have no idea how to do this, if any one can help, I will really respect about it.

```
<serial>KLH4587KIJ</serial> <!--    100001  -->
<serial>MHF4557PDS</serial> <!--    100002  -->
```

Comment: Why do you need to read the value of a comment?  Comments are meant to carry information that's only of concern to humans, not computers.  If the computer needs to know the value then you should probably mark the value up properly instead.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps that information should be an attribute of `serial`. However it may be a purely educational question. I hope so.

Answer (score 4):

Use the next code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<serials><serial>KLH4587KIJ</serial><!-- 100001 --><serial>MHF4557PDS</serial><!-- 100002 --></serials>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment){
    var_dump($comment->textContent);
}
```

As you can see, you have to encapsulate the `serial` tag in a parent `serials`

You can see it works here: http://codepad.org/UoZvPxjl

---

**Edit. Added line number:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<serials><serial>KLH4587KIJ</serial><!-- 100001 --><serial>MHF4557PDS</serial><!-- 100002 --></serials>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$lineNo = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query('//serial/following::comment()') as $comment){
    $serial= $xpath->query('//serial', $comment)->item($lineNo)->textContent;
    var_dump ("Line number: ".$lineNo ." Serial number: ".$serial." Comented number: ".$comment->textContent);
    $lineNo++;
}
```

You can see this in action here: http://codepad.org/4igoDzWN

Comment: Great help tomloprod, an one thing, can you please tell me how to read that line number (node line number) of the xml document?

Comment: @user3619039 You can use `getLineNo` method. 
Here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php

Comment: You could also use a counter... `$lineNo = 0;` and after the `var_dump`, inside the `foreach`: `$lineNo++;`

Comment: Hi,
can you please show me how to get e.g (line num : 4 | serial num : PQE430015069 | comented num : 3693 )